# click event shoot parent click

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var clicked = false;

// Resolving inherit issue blub form start click
.on(_.aClick, 'ul > li', function() {

    if (!clicked) {

        // only when click li ...
    }
    else { clicked = false; }
})

// Start click
.on(_.aClick, '.b', function() {

    clicked = true;

})
```

I have 2 click events built in a class helping with jquery library, suppose that the class .b is above to class .a .
When I click in a .b layer, this shoot the click event in .b , but the click event of li , too . my way to take with this 
isse is this method, but I suppose if we have any suggestion to create a cleaner code , or more responsive. anyway why 
y have this issue ?? . in my css code , de z-index of .b is bigger, but not works to me . Thanks for any helpfull and sorry 
for my bad english im a practicer.

Comment: It's the event bubbling.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing

Comment: Thanks ibrahim ,good link that iI need to read